# why does xoauth have a problem saving the keychain

Tags: token, keychain, xero-api

running windows 7
need to do machine to machine Xero updates
don't mind initially getting user to authenticate but after that the system should run unattended.

using XOAuth to setup client details, authentication is good BUT get an error saving the keychain

Storing tokens in local keychain
failed to save tokens to keychain: The stub received bad data.

Why am I getting this error, I can see all the tokens in the browser and in the console

What's going on??  I cannot use XOAuth ??

Someone out there tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using PKCE? I am, and get something similar. But the access token and refresh token work from my service.

Answer (score 0):

there are some dependencies for certain windows versions that have a known bug for Xoauth. Is the `access_token` still being put to STDOUT?